# Differentiate inside model `validate` if it is creating or updating an item?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm searching for other way than using `this.isNewRecord`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One just can add the validations in a `beforeCreate` hook.